Covering a domain with polydisks
Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain and $u,v \in G$. Then, there exists a continuous path $\phi : I = [a,b] \to G$ such that $u$ and $v$ are joined by $\phi$. Since $\phi(I)$ is compact, it can be covered by finitely many polydisks $U_1, \ldots, U_l$ such that $U_k \subset G$ for $k=1,\ldots,l$.
Now in my textbook it sayts that "It is easy to show that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $t', t'' \in I$ with $|t'-t''| < \delta$ we have that $\phi(t')$ and $\phi(t'')$ are in the same polydisk $U_k$".
But I don't know how to show that there exists that $\delta$. I think that it results from continuity of $\phi$ but I still don't know how to prove it. And if I have two intersecting circles, then if I take a point on boundary of intersection, then I can't find such $\delta$ I think...


note that $\phi(t)$ is always in the interior of one of the polydisks (it can be in the boundary of one, but then it must also be in the interior of another)

@Albert, so if i take $A$ be the intersection points of $\phi(I)$ with the polydisks $U_1, \ldots, U_l$ and take $\delta:=\displaystyle\min_{\substack{t_i,, t_j \in \phi^{-1}(A)} \ t_i \ne t_j} |t_i - t_j|$ then will be ok?

Doesn't this remind you of the Lebesgue number of a covering of a compact set in a metric space?

@TedShifrin umm.. I don't know what the Lebsegue number of a covering of a compact set is.

So what I've said in comment don't work?

I don't understand what you wrote. The Lebesgue number is fundamental and you should learn it. Check any point-set topology book or even look on Wikipedia.
